# Modular system with exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have the following modular equetion system and I am struggling for the past few days to find the solution. I have to find p and q such that:

**c1 = (2*p + 3*q)^e1 mod N**

**c2 = (5*p + 7*q)^e2 mod N**

Where **N = p*q** and **N,c1,c2,e1,e2** some **known** big integers.
I tried multiple things to find a solution including Fermat's little theorem.

**Approach 1**

(2*p + 3*q)^e1 ≡ (2*p + 3*q) mod e1 (e1 prime)

(5*p + 7*q)^e2 ≡ (5*p + 7*q) mod e2 (e2 prime)

So

(2*p + 3*q)^e1 = n1*N + c1

**n2 * e1 + (2*p + 3*q) = n1*N + c1**

Similiarly for the second equetion I got:

**n4 * e2 + (5p + 7q) = n3*N + c2**

Solving the system we have something like:

**p = -7*N*n1 + 3*N*n3 - 7*c1 + 3*c2 + 7*e1*n2 - 3*e2*n4**

**q = 5*N*n1 - 2*N*n3 + 5*c1 - 2*c2 - 5*e1*n2 + 2*e2*n4**

But I guess is almost imposible to test all ni to see when N=p*q is integer

**Approach 2**

Using the binomial theorem for one equetion I noticed that:

**(2*p + 3*q)^e1 ≡ (2*p)^e1 + (3*q)^e1 mod N** because all the middle terms are multiple of N

but this couldnt help me at all

Comment: Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with the binomial theorem.

$$c_1 \equiv (2p + 3q)^{e_1} \mod N\\
c_2 \equiv (5p + 7q)^{e_2} \mod N$$

First make the exponents the same:

$$c_1^{e_2} \equiv (2p + 3q)^{e_1e_2} \mod N\\
c_2^{e_1} \equiv (5p + 7q)^{e_1e_2} \mod N$$

Now apply the binomial theorem trick using the fact that $N=pq$:

$$c_1^{e_2} \equiv (2p)^{e_1e_2} + (3q)^{e_1e_2} \mod N\\
c_2^{e_1} \equiv (5p)^{e_1e_2} + (7q)^{e_1e_2} \mod N$$

$$c_1^{e_2} \equiv 2^{e_1e_2}p^{e_1e_2} + 3^{e_1e_2}q^{e_1e_2} \mod N\\
c_2^{e_1} \equiv 5^{e_1e_2}p^{e_1e_2} + 7^{e_1e_2}q^{e_1e_2} \mod N$$

These are two linear modular equations with the unknowns $p^{e_1e_2}$ and $q^{e_1e_2}$ so we can solve them to get:

$$p^{e_1e_2} \equiv n_1 \mod N\\
q^{e_1e_2} \equiv n_2 \mod N$$

So we now have two non-zero integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ which are smaller than $N$ but which also satisfy:

$$n_1n_2\equiv p^{e_1e_2}q^{e_1e_2}\equiv(pq)^{e_1e_2}=N^{e_1e_2}\equiv0 \mod N$$

So $N=pq$ divides $n_1n_2$, hence $p$, $q$ each divide one of $n_1$ and $n_2$. Note that they cannot both divide the same one since $n_1,n_2<N=pq$. Therefore you can recover $p$ and $q$ by calculating $\gcd(N,n_1)$ and $\gcd(N,n_2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Can you please explain more the last paragraph consept?

Comment: I mean, how we know that if a product divides another product then the two terms of the first product each, divides the other two terms? Also, with the above statement true, we know for example that p divides both N and n1 or n2. But why p is the gcd of N and ni?

Comment: @NickGeo We know that $N$ is the product of two primes, $p$ and $q$. So the only divisors of $N$ are $1$, $p$, $q$, and $N$ itself. A gcd of $N$ is such a divisor, so can also only be one of those values. But these gcd's can't be $N$ since $n_1, n_2<N$. We also know that the primes $p$ and $q$ must occur in these gcd's since $n_1n_2$ is divisible by $p$ and by $q$. If a prime divides a product, then that prime divides (at least) one of its factors.

Comment: So it's possible for p or q to divide both n1 and n2? In that case both gcds would be same. But I guess if even that's the case, I can get the other one (for example q) as q=N/p

Comment: @NickGeo No, $p$ and $q$ cannot divide both divide $n_1$ because then $pq$ would divide $n_1$ and that is impossible because we know $n_1<N$. The same goes for $n_2$. But we do know that $p$ must divide one of them and $q$ must divide one of them. So either we have $p|n_1$ and $q|n_2$ or we have $p|n_2$ and $q|n_1$.

Comment: Okay now I get it. Thank you very much again, it was really helpful

Comment: Currently I have a problem finding the solution in the system. I am in a state where
a = bp mod N but a and b are huge numbers and I cant find a k such that a=kb mod N. I am using python pow() function to apply calculations

Comment: @NickGeo I don't understand your description of what you are trying to do. BTW, you are using the 3-argument version of the pow() function, right? So you can use for example pow(a,-1,N) to get the inverse of a modulo N. (needs python 3)

Comment: Yes I am using this version. Maybe I can find b^-1 and multiply it with bp and a. Then I will have a*b^-1 = p mod N. In previously easier cases I was just trying to express a as a multiple of b modulo n (a=kb mod n) so then I could divide both sides with b and have p = k mod N but with big numbers this is really hard

Comment: @NickGeo Yes, to solve $p$ from $bp\equiv a \pmod N$ you have to multiply both sides by the modular inverse of $b$ to get $p\equiv b^{-1}a \pmod N$. So it's just one inversion mod $N$, and one multiplication mod $N$ to get the answer.